# Using regex to restrict user input

Tags: regex

There is a particular field in my application where a user will be asked to enter a time for a job to be run (like HH:MM) for the MM field, I want the user to enter a number in the range 0-59 ONLY. How should I pattern match this with regexp ?

Comment: Programming language used? There are a couple of plugins for ie `jQuery`.

Comment: I am using TCL 8.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this regex:

```
^[0-5]?[0-9]$
```

This will allow an optional first digit of `0-5` followed by any second digit.

But I would rather just check the numerical value in your code (JavaScript), since this is much easier to handle there.

## Regex101

Comment: Thanks. Actually the field uses a regex mask in code, so any invalid input causes the text box to get marked in red. Until now there was no check for this. So I am just putting this in now.